# Rudin 8.3 justification for swapping double summations?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In theorem 8.3 in Rudin PMA, Rudin swaps an infinite sum with a finite sum without comment. What is the justification for this step?

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}$$

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: He's just using the fact that if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d_i$ converge, then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(c_i + d_i)$ converges and equals $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d_i$. By induction, this extends from two sequences $(c_i)$ and $(d_i)$ to $n$ sequences $(a_{i1}), (a_{i2}), \ldots, (a_{in})$. That said, this proof is appalling IMO. Rudin may find it more interesting, but it's certainly not as understandable or insightful as a straightforward proof.

Comment: Rudin's books are very nicely written with proofs striving for economy and interdependence within the text. The opinion that this argument is appalling is a shortsighted one.

Comment: You can compare how this argument relates/extends to the one of the more general Fubini's theorem. I don't know if Fubini's theorem is present in PMA, but it is certainly in RCA.

Comment: @plop I have plenty of respect and love for PMA and RCA. But there are a few proofs I don't like, at least in the context where they appear. This is one of them. But of course opinions vary - that's why there are so many analysis books out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easier to see if you unpack the finite sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_{i1} + a_{i2} + \ldots + a_{in})$$
I'm sure that Rudin has proved by this point that if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d_i$ converge, then so does $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(c_i + d_i)$, and we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(c_i + d_i) + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}d_i$$
And since this holds for two sequences $(c_i)$ and $(d_i)$, by induction it holds for $n$ sequences $(a_{i1}), (a_{i2}), \ldots, (a_{in})$. Therefore,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_{i1} + a_{i2} + \ldots + a_{in}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i1} + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i2} + \ldots + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{in}$$
Converting this back to the more compact notation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$
Since this equality holds for every $n$, and we know the LHS has a limit as $n \to \infty$, we can take limits of both sides to conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$

Comment: Such a clear answer thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If in a double summation there involves a finite sum, then the order of the summation can be swapped.

Indeed,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{(a_{i1}+\ldots+a_{in})}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i1}+\ldots+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{in}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|a_{ij}|\le \sum_{j=1}^\infty|a_{ij}|=b_i$ for every $i,j\in \mathbb N$.

**Given any $j\in \mathbb N$, by comparison test, $\sum_i|a_{ij}|$ converges. It follows that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$ converges.**

$\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^ma_{ij}$. It follows that

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^ma_{ij}=\lim_{m\to \infty}(\sum_{i=1}^ma_{i1}+\sum_{i=1}^ma_{i2}+\cdots+\sum_{i=1}^ma_{in})\tag 1$$

By the bolded part above, RHS of $(1)$ is $: \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i1}+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{i2}+\cdots+\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{in}= \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij}$